# Realm crashes item deleted. But I do requery Realm first

Tags: android, database, realm, illegalstateexception, staledataexception

I get back a response and I do this:

```
 if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.has("results")) {
                try {
                    final JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(PSApplicationClass.Config);
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            try {
                                realm.delete(Beacon.class);
                                realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Beacon.class, array);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("", "error is: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                            if (back != null)
                                back.onResponse("");
                        }
                    });
                    realm.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", "error trying to fetch user beacons: " + e.getMessage());
                    if (back != null)
                        back.onResponse("");
                }
            }
```

This is in my Beacon.java model class.
Now after that, in my Activity, I do this:

```
 public void setBeaconsInList() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(PSApplicationClass.Config);
    RealmResults<Beacon> beaconsResults = realm.where(Beacon.class).findAll();
    if (beaconsResults != null && beaconsResults.size() > 0) {
        for (Beacon beacon : beaconsResults) {
             for (Beacon beacon : beaconsResults) {
                if (!beacons.contains(beacon)) {
                    if (beacon.getUser_vehicle() != null) {
                        beacons.add(0, beacon);
                        userBeaconAdapter.addItemFirst(beacon);
                    } else {
                        beacons.add(beacon);
                        userBeaconAdapter.addItem(beacon);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    userBeaconAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    realm.close();
}
```

I get this error:

```
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow.nativeGetIndex(Native Method)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow.getIndex(UncheckedRow.java:137)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at io.realm.BeaconRealmProxy.equals(BeaconRealmProxy.java:851)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:339)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.activities.PSUserBeaconsActivity.setBeaconsInList(PSUserBeaconsActivity.java:144)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.activities.PSUserBeaconsActivity$2.onResponse(PSUserBeaconsActivity.java:126)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.model.vehicle.Beacon$1.onResponse(Beacon.java:117)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.utils.WSCalls$1.onResponse(WSCalls.java:98)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.utils.WSCalls$1.onResponse(WSCalls.java:77)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-16 17:39:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Why does this happen? If I recreate my realm instance, and I requery, why does it return objects that where deleted?
I just want to show the remaining objects.

If not, is there a different way, of checking and deleting the objects that were not updated from the server?

Comment: You're deleting all the existing `Beacon` objects and then you're using the `createOrUpdateAllFromJson()` function which effectively creates a set of `Beacon` objects into the Realm. I'm guessing the objects received from the JSON are mostly equal to the objects already present in the database (maybe those are just updates?), so the created `Beacon` objects in Realm may contain the same information. Still, when you do the `realm.delete(Beacon.class);` you're deleting the objects you was keeping a reference to, crashing your application. I recommend you to just perform an update, no deletions.

Comment: But then, when a user deletes an objects from the website, or an Iphone. When I call createOrUpdateAllFromJson(), it updates the new Beacons, BUT does not remove from the db the old ones.
The thing is that as you can see, I delete them, to have a clean db, I create my objects. but then I requery for my objects. I would assume that after commiting my changes. The query will not provide me with stale data (objects that were deleted)
A Better way to reformulate my question, is how can I remove the objects that are not updated

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot. I found the issue. made an answer. Wasn't clearing the adapter, and before adding new data, I was checking if it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Orlando's comment, I figured it out. my list was being compared with the objects inside my adapter, and because of my change, the objects from the adapter where stale. That's where my logic went wrong. It's not that the new query was stale, but I didn't clear the adapter.
So doing this before fixed it:

```
  beacons.clear();
  userBeaconAdapter.clearItems();
```